# Join elements from a list of dictionaries in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a list like this:

```
[{species: "cat", weight: 100}, 
 {species: "dog", weight: 120}, 
 {species: "bird", weight: 20}]
```

Now I want to convert it into something like

(1) `cat, dog, bird`

(2) `<ul><li>cat</li><li>dog</li><li>bird</li></ul>`

I found Javascript has a `join` method for array, but I wonder whether there is a convenient way in jQuery or Javascript that can extract the element from the list of dictionaries.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `$.each()` in this context to iterate the array with objects,

```
var array = [{species: "cat", weight: 100}, 
 {species: "dog", weight: 120}, 
 {species: "bird", weight: 20}];

var ul = $('<ul>');
$.each(array,function(i,val){
  ul.append($('<li>',{text:val.species}));
})

$('body').append(ul);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rbG66/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use $.map

```
 var species = [{species: "cat", weight: 100}, 
               {species: "dog", weight: 120}, 
               {species: "bird", weight: 20}]
 var arr = $.map(species, function(obj) { return obj["species"]; })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map` method:

```
var plucked = arr.map(function(elem) {
   return elem.species;
});

var list = "<ul><li>" + plucked.join('</li><li>') + "</li></ul>";
```

Please note that IE8 and below doesn't support the `map` method, you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), or if you are loading jQuery, you can use it's `$.map` utility function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var a =[{species: "cat", weight: 100}, 
 {species: "dog", weight: 120}, 
 {species: "bird", weight: 20}];
var newUl = $("<ul/>", {});

$.each(a, 
       function(){
           var list = $("<li/>", {});
           var text = this.species;
           $(list).html(text);
           $(list).appendTo(newUl);
       });

$(newUl).appendTo("body");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6j4S/6/)